# Sink detection algorithm with Pascal language

Tags: pascal

I have an implementation to Pascal about sink detection in a graph. Here is the code :

```
FUNCTION KATAVOTHRA (A:MATRIX; N:INTEGER): INTEGER;
VAR 
  I,J,K,S:INTEGER;
BEGIN
  KATAVOTHRA:=0;  
  I:=1;
  WHILE (KATAVOTHRA=0 AND I<N) DO   {1}
  BEGIN
    J:=1;
    WHILE (A[I,J]=0 AND J<N) DO J:=J+1;  {2}
    IF (J=N) THEN BEGIN
      S:=0;
      FOR K:=1 TO N DO S:=S+A[K,I];
      IF (S=N-1) THEN 
        KATAVOTHRA:=1;
    END;
    I:=I+1;
  END;    
END;
```

Assuming that we have the following adjacency matrix :

```
 0 0 1
 1 0 1
 0 0 0
```

for `V1` , `V2` and `V3` vertexes. (1 code if we have a connection between two nodes or zero code otherwise).

I am trying to trace the code with this input but I can't. The reason is I don't take an result when I is 3. Let's see what I have done so far: (`KATAVOTHRA` is the name of sink).

`BEGIN with I:=1; and J:=1` (INSIDE the first while loop)

first we check `A[1,1]` if is zero and it is ( 1 < 3 of course in order to continue) so `J= J+1 => J=2`

`A[1,2]` is zero too so increment again J and now J is 3.  3 is not less than 3 and `A[1,3]` is not 0. So we are going to IF statement `IF( J = N) => IF( 3 = 3 ) then S=0 (sum)` 
so we are going to the FOR loop and we summarize `A[1,1] + A[2,1] + A[3,1]`

`IF( S = N-1) THEN` we have found a sink. But here `S=1` not 2. We go out of FOR loop , I will be 2 now Again `WHILE(KATAVOTHRA=0 AND 2<3)` J is 1 we check now `A[2,1]` but is not zero and 2 is not 3 so we go out ... and I will be now 3.... but this time 3 < 3 is false so the whole loop terminates there? I can't understand (I have no much experience in Pascal lagnuage though).

What is wrong with this?

Comment: The code with the matrix here http://ideone.com/ziz5Ms

Comment: So are you passing in 4 for N (since your matrix appears to be 1-based)? (comment re-posted due to typo)

Comment: Yes it is 1-based not zero based. Matrix comes from 3 vertexes V1 , V2 , V3 . What do you mean by 4? Imagine a graph with 3 nodes. V1 and V2 have one outcoming edge to V3 and one edge from V2 to V1 . V1-> V3  , V2->V3 and V2->V1.

Comment: In your code you check that your indexes into the matrix are less than N, so to cover all of it your N value must be 4 for a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: But N is the number of vertexes? It is fixed How can I change it? My matrix is correct? I really cannot understand sorry :( Give an example. The counter in the loops starts from 1.If you have 3x3 matrix you have 3 nodes... isn't it?

Comment: My tracing of the algorithm above is correct?

Comment: Pascal arrays don't always start at a certain value. You need to show the actual declaration of your `MATRIX` type. The proper range can be `0..2`, `1..3`, or `-99..-97`, depending on how it was declared.  (Why is all of your code in CAPS? It makes it much harder to read and understand. They put a Shift key on the keyboard for a reason, but if you're not going to use it at least use all lower-case, which is much easier on the eyes.)

Comment: A description of the algorithm (in greek) can be found here, http://www.dblab.ece.ntua.gr/courses/DS/palies_askhseis/2001/ask4-01-lysh.pdf. Unfortunately google translate could not help here.

Comment: Ken White I agree with you. But consider what it will happen when you approach the line IF( S = N - 1) if matrix is 3x3 and the second parameter (The N variable in the function) is 4 then N-1 is 3 but our example (if you look at the matrix) gives 2 not 3. Am I wrong somewhere? and where?  LU RD this is the description not a tracing like here. I don't know if is better idea to start from zero until 3 to the loops instead of 1 as it is now.

Answer (score 1):

> and I will be now 3.... but this time 3 < 3 is false so the whole loop terminates there?

As you already have remarked does your loop end one number too early.
To circumvent this you must test for `I <= N`.

Here a short program to show the two variants:

```
PROGRAM LoopTest;

VAR
   i : Integer;

BEGIN
   WriteLn("Example with <");
   i := 0;
   WHILE (i < 3) DO
   BEGIN
      WriteLn(" Loopvar: ", i);
      i := i + 1;
   END;
   WriteLn;

   WriteLn("Example with <=");
   i := 1;
   WHILE (i <= 3) DO
   BEGIN
      WriteLn(" Loopvar: ", i);
      i := i + 1;
   END;
END.
```

And the output:

> ```
> Example with <
>  Loopvar: 0
>  Loopvar: 1
>  Loopvar: 2
>
> Example with <=
>  Loopvar: 1
>  Loopvar: 2
>  Loopvar: 3
> ```

It is now easy to see:

- `<` is used for zero based arrays
- `<=` is used for one  based arrays